# How are fields and properties linked?

Tags: c#

A book I'm working through (Wrox Beginning Visual C# 2012, which so far is a great book) uses this class in an example:

```
class Farm<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Animal
{
    private List<T> animals = new List<T>();

    public List<T> Animals
    {
        get
        {
            return animals;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return animals.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return animals.GetEnumerator();
    }
    //...
}
```

My question is: How does the compiler "know" that the property "Animals" and the field "animals" are linked, such that when, in the program, I instantiate a `Farm<Animal>` and then say `myFarm.Animals.Add(new Cow());` the object gets added to the private list? I know that this is true because I can see that the enumerator iterates over `animals` and therefore therefore when I say `foreach (Animal animal in myFarm)` I'm seeing the objects in `animals` which I previously added to `Animals`.

This makes a lot more sense to me when we're talking about a simple field like an int. In that case it seems obvious that when I set `MyInt=1` and this results in `myInt==1`, it's because the property is linked to the field by a `set` accessor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't "know" they are "linked." It is simply executing this code:

```
public List<T> Animals
{
    get
    {
        return animals;
    }
}
```

When you write `myFarm.Animals.Add(...)`, the runtime executes the *getter method* for your `Animals` property. This method returns `animals` (because that's how you wrote it). The `Add()` method then gets called on the result.

I think your confusion may be that you feel like you are "modifying" the `Animals` property, and therefore you expect a `set` to be involved. This is not the case. The property is simply a place to get or put a reference to an object of type `List<T>`. You aren't creating a new list or making the reference point to a different list. The reference stays the same. You're simply calling a method on the referred-to object. This is why it's only the property's *getter* which is being called.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! To make sure I understand this: It works because List<T> is a reference type, right? "get" provides a reference to animals, and so Animals.Add() is sort of like a reference or pointer to animals.Add()?

Comment: It would "sort of" work the same way even if the property's type were a value type. Your property's getter would still be called. However, the method would be called on a *temporary copy* of the value returned by your getter (so any side effects of the getter on the value type would be essentially lost). I personally tend to avoid using value-typed properties for this reason, unless the type is immutable, but that is just my preference.